# Formatting using clojure

Tags: list, clojure, formatting, set, comparison

**Context**

I have a list and a set with similar data in two different formats.

```
("XXX_1_10/22/2015" "YYY_1.5_11/22/2015" "XX_2.5_10/23/2015" "YY_5_11/26/2015")

#{"XXX 1.000 OCT15" "XX 2.500 OCT2015" "ZZZ 3.500 JAN2016"}
```

I need to get a list which is common between these two data structures using 
clojure.

Which should be:

```
("XXX 1.000 OCT15" "XX 2.500 OCT2015")
```

**Question**

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Your second data format `{...}` is a *map*. Surely it should be  `#{}` - a *set*.

Comment: I'm unable to change the format in the data structures. I have teste dthe way to compare both of them using (keep #set list) and it returns the common values. But formatting the date to make them similar is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: feel free to add that code.  it makes it easier for someone willing to answer to build on it

Answer (score 0):

you have to normalize all the values first. do it using regexp.

```
(def months ["JAN" "FEB" "MAR" "APR" 
             "MAY" "JUN" "JUL" "AUG" 
             "SEP" "OCT" "NOV" "DEC"])

(defn normalize-underscored [value]
  (let [[_ text val month year]
        (re-matches #"(.+?)_([\d.]+)_(\d+)/\d+/(\d{4})" value)]
    [text
     (Float/parseFloat val)
     (months (dec (Long/parseLong month)))
     year]))

(defn normalize-spaced [value]
  (let [[_ text val month year]
        (re-matches #"(.+?)\s([\d.]+)\s(\w{3})(\d{2,4})" value)]
    [text (Float/parseFloat val) month
     (if (== 2 (count year)) (str "20" year) year)]))
```

that is how it normalizes:

```
user> (normalize-underscored "XX_2.5_10/23/2015")
["XX" 2.5 "OCT" "2015"]
user> (normalize-spaced "XXX 1.000 OCT15")
["XXX" 1.0 "OCT" "2015"]
user> (normalize-spaced "ZZZ 3.500 JAN2016")
["ZZZ" 3.5 "JAN" "2016"]
```

and then just compare normalized versions:

```
(def underscored '("XXX_1_10/22/2015" "YYY_1.5_11/22/2015"
                   "XX_2.5_10/23/2015" "YY_5_11/26/2015"))

(def spaced #{"XXX 1.000 OCT15" "XX 2.500 OCT2015" 
              "ZZZ 3.500 JAN2016"})

(for [uv (map normalize-underscored underscored)
      s spaced
      :when (= uv (normalize-spaced s))]
  s)
```

output:

```
("XXX 1.000 OCT15" "XX 2.500 OCT2015")
```

or better reformat the result to a more consistent form, like this:

```
(map (partial apply format "%s %.3f %s%s")
     (keep (set (map normalize-spaced spaced))
           (map normalize-underscored underscored)))
```

output:

```
("XXX 1.000 OCT2015" "XX 2.500 OCT2015")
```